# PHP 5.6 error "Unable to connect to ssl://" after upgrade from PHP 5.5 in FreeBSD

Tags: php, magento, ssl, freebsd, pyopenssl

I'm having trouble withe a payment method in Magento, after a upgrade of PHP 5.5 to version 5.6.

After the upgrade the payment method in Magento 1.9 throws an error and generates a report (see below).

My payment provider says that the payment extension uses "Zend_Http_Client transport protocol".

Anyone know what can cause this after the upgrade of PHP?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:56:"Unable to Connect to ssl://api.payson.se:443. Error
#0: ";i:1;s:2213:"
#0 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/lib/Zend/Http/Client.php(1073): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->connect('api.payson.se', 443, true)
#1 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/community/Payson/Payson/Helper/Api.php(1181): Zend_Http_Client->request('POST')
#2 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/community/Payson/Payson/Model/Method/Abstract.php(126): Payson_Payson_Helper_Api->PaymentDetails('204103')
#3 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(1152): Payson_Payson_Model_Method_Abstract->cancel(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#4 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(865): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_void(true, NULL, 'cancel')
#5 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1155): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->cancel()
#6 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/community/Payson/Payson/controllers/CheckoutController.php(62): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->cancel()
#7 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/community/Payson/Payson/controllers/CheckoutController.php(92): Payson_Payson_CheckoutController->cancelOrder('Unable to Conne...')
#8 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Payson_Payson_CheckoutController->redirectAction()
#9 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('redirect')
#10 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /usr/local/www/apache24/webroot/multistore/index.php(83): Mage::run('mystore', 'store')
#14 {main}";s:3:"url";s:26:"/payson/checkout/redirect/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:8:"mystore";}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can connect with TLS 1.0 (and above) when using *Server Name Indication* (SNI) and the *GeoTrust Global CA* root ca. The certificate path validates as expected, and you can see it in `s_client` with ***`Verify return code: 0 (ok)`***. You should ensure all three in your configuration.

We can't really say more from the OpenSSL point of view based on the exception because it lacks the detail we need. Maybe someone more familiar with PHP or Magento will recognize the problem and call it out for you.

```
$ wget https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem
...
Saving to: ‘GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem’    
...
‘GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem’ saved [1234/1234]
```

And:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.payson.se:443 -servername api.payson.se:443 -tls1 -CAfile GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = SE, ST = Solna, L = Solna, O = Payson AB, OU = IT, CN = *.payson.se
verify return:1
Server did acknowledge servername extension.
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=SE/ST=Solna/L=Solna/O=Payson AB/OU=IT/CN=*.payson.se
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=SE/ST=Solna/L=Solna/O=Payson AB/OU=IT/CN=*.payson.se
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3236 bytes and written 262 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 514B0000016FC6A78475CFF088BF92B511EA2A593E7A3C21CB7606096400616A
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 9EF49EC4B639D63B92003016C3456303D688775502D97D6ACD158F3CD64DF08F
                F626374D68B7ADD6BF24D222C198129C
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1477375819
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
```

Finally:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0b  26 Sep 2016
```